# Lock predictors subset before final model building

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, feature-selection, blocking, tuning

Let assume that we have a training test and a test set with unseen data.
I perform monte carlo cross valitation on training set to tune hyper-parameters. The question is related to feature selection.
The standard approach is to implement FS inside the MCCV, so for different MCCV iterations different features are selected. I want to know if it is legit to perform a completely independent feature selection before model train on the whole training set, so in this way it is completely disconnected from the rest of the algorithm. Feature selection has its own MCCV and end with selection of features based on the cumulative frequency of occurrence among MCCV rounds. This is beacuse I want to tune my ML model with a fixed subset of predictors.
Finally model is re-trained using best hyper-parameters and then tested one-shot on the unseed data of test set to have a reliable evaluation of model performance.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It sounds like you have developed a model and validated its performance, so now that you have a model you like, you want to use that exact model to make new predictions. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the dataset is small and I did not excract a subset for independent validation. Feature selection is an initial stand-alone fase before model costruction, so I have an MCCV loop for feature selection and then an MCCV loop for model train/val. The FS loop end with selection of features based on the cumulative frequency of occurrence among 100 rounds. I would simply like to perform train/val by locking the feature subset and model paramenters. Model paramenters are tune manually with multiple attempts. I obtain lower performance in this way...

Comment: I do not follow what you are doing. It sounds like what you have done is create a model that you now want to use to make new predictions. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Thank you Dave for your indications. I have rewritten my question in a more clear form, I hope...